# How to start multiple Erlang nodes in single Windows system?

Tags: windows, erlang, erl

I want to start multiple Erlang nodes inside single Windows 7 machine to test distributed program. I gave following command to start one node but its not working.

```
C:\Users\Shekhar>erl -sname foo -setcookie erlang
Error spawning C:\PROGRA~1\ERL510~1.2\ERTS-5~1.2\bin\epmd -daemon (error 0)

C:\Users\Shekhar>
```

I have erlang in `C:\Program Files\erl5.10.2` directory and there's no executable with the name `epmd` in `C:\Program Files\erl5.10.2\erts-5.10.2\bin` directory or inside `C:\Program Files\erl5.10.2\bin` directory.

Can anyone please tell how do I start multiple Erlang nodes in single system?

Comment: Multiple erlang nodes require epmd so they can find each other. If your erlang installation is missing epmd, perhaps you need to rebuild and/or reinstall.

Comment: epmd.exe must be in erlVxx\ertsVxx\bin. if you can't find it, you should check the Erlang installation, or simply install the latest version. From my experience, in windows system, there is nothing more to do than launching the otp_win64_17.3.exe

Comment: You can also try packages: https://www.erlang-solutions.com/downloads/download-erlang-otp Whatever is easier for you.